# Oauth2.0 Google API token issue - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have trouble creating a Google API OAuth2.0 token though following all the steps here: [OAuth2 Authentication](
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication?authuser=1)

When trying to create the token through the OAuth2.0 playground:
[OAUTH 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

[image]

I end up with this error:
[image: Error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch]

Discussion on similar threads tried to give some guidance but without any luck in my case.

Comment: Have you tried creating an OAuth token in the cloud console? https://console.cloud.google.com

Comment: Go to the console and add the callback url. Make sure it matches

Answer (score 3):

Add google.com in the authorized domain list of your app's OAuth consent screen.

[image]

Click on the application for which you want to configure for the next step:

[image]

Make sure to also add 'https://developers.google.com' in the Authorized JavaScript origins and 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground' in the Authorized redirect URIs[click 'save' below once added]:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are applying your own client id and client secret to [Oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)  you are also using browser credentials.

For browser credentials to work it must be able to return the token to an endpoint that can handle it and that endpoint (Redirect uri) must be registered in the Google Developer console for that project.

if you check your first picture under the check box you clicked

> You will need to list the URL https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground as a valid redirect URI in your Google APIs Console's project. Then enter the client ID and secret assigned to a web application on your project below:

Try adding that URL as it says.